# Can't run Lightswitch 2012 Program under Windows XP Take 2

Tags: command-prompt, visual-studio-lightswitch, dumpbin

I have exactly the same problem as the one raised and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140643/cant-run-lightswitch-2012-programm-under-windows-xp). I've got a LS desktop app that refuses to work on XP SP3.

However, I have absolutely no idea how to use the command prompt and dumpbin. I've managed to find the command prompt (which was really big of me) and with the LS project loaded up in VS2012 I've run the commands stated, but I get the following error:

> Command "dumpbin" is not valid

This is obviously my complete ignorance of how to do this, so could someone explain or point me to a tutorial (preferably one with lots of pictures!!)

As I understand it, I need to get the LS app to utilise .net 4 rather than .net 4.5. If there is another means to do this I'd be very grateful for the help.

Shine On,

Numb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sussed out how to get dumpbin and editbin to work. Didn't realise you need to navigate to the path of the item you want to change.

How dumb is that!